# wp7 audio files for words

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating an app for flash cards and I need some words as speech. If you have use a good software that can perform a text to speech conversion and provide the audio files, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the Microsoft Translator API/service and see if it meets the needs for your scenario:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hey use Natural Soft i have used it, it is a good one.
You can look into it through here http://www.naturalreaders.com/index.htm